# HttpReceiveClientCertificate doesn't work for firefox

Tags: c++, ssl, https

I want create https server in c++ by Microsoft http server api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364510(v=vs.85).aspx

every things is OK in IE and chrome

but in firefox HttpReceiveClientCertificate return 1168 ERROR_NOT_FOUND error

because pClientCertInfo struct is null

i attach image

[image]

Comment: Code please, instead of image...

Comment: Have you installed the client certificate in FF correctly?

Comment: this is sample code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931705/microsoft-c-http-server-api-httpapi-lib-httpreceiveclientcertificate-functio

Comment: work correctly for IE and chrome